# Spring cloud stream kafka - A subscribable channel has no output

Tags: spring, spring-boot, memory-management, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have an application which does a lot of data processing (in the order of ~1.3 million at a time) which happens in bursts. The application consumes data from a kafka topic.

I'm using a version 2.0.1 of spring-cloud-stream-starter-kafka to consume data.

My code is as follows:

Listener:

```
@Service
public class ListenerService {

    @Autowired
    private Application2<Foo> application;

    @Override
    @StreamListener(FooStreams.INPUT)
    public void subscribe(@Payload Foo foo) {
        application.sync(foo);
    }
}
```

Streams:

```
public interface FooStreams {

    String INPUT = "Foo";

    @Input(value = INPUT)
    SubscribableChannel subscribe();

}
```

In the main application, I've bound the stream to kafka like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding({FooStreams.class})
public class Application {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Application failed to start");
        }

    }
}
```

Is there something I am missing? The issue is that I can see that the memory utilization spikes up during the time of data processing, which doesn't come down after the processing is done.

Comment: We can't possibly say without knowing what's behind `application.sync(foo);`

Comment: That just saves the record to a database, or updates if the same key exists. My doubt is if I need to have an output for the same stream. I have a feeling that it is creating a lot of listener threads for so many records, which don't close.

Comment: Sure, we can speculate, but without seeing the code behind " just saves the record to a database" and configuration of your application we can't say for sure. One thing I can recommend is to disconnect (temporarily) the write to the database and see what's going on. Basically go through the process of elimination.